# How to detect a Three.js component type for useRef?

Tags: reactjs, three.js

I want to attach a `ref` to a Three.js component called `OrbitControls`:

```
const orbitControls = useRef<any | null>(null);
...
<OrbitControls ref={orbitControls} />
```

My question in general is:

How can I detect an external library type for useRef? Because ESLint rule throws me an error about using `any` and I don't want to remove the rule from the project configuration.

Thanks